# Problema con Git Push

Tags: git, git-push

tengo un problema con un repositorio remoto al cual antes ya había hecho un push.
Y es que estoy intentado hacer de nuevo un push y me aparece este error:

> kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
> banner exchange: Connection to 140.82.113.4 port 22: Software caused
> connection abort fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Comment: ¿Podría tratarse de un error (quizás termporal) del servidor? ¿Se trata de algún servidor conocido como Github, GitLab o Bitbucket, o es uno privado? ¿Funcionan otros repositorios albergados en el mismo servidor?

Comment: Es de GitHub. Y otros repositorios tampoco funcionan.

Comment: ¿Podría tratarse de que no estés en la rama correcta? Verifica que la rama a la que estás intentando hacer push existe y verifica si el repositorio existe también. Saludos.

Comment: Puede ser problema temporal del servidor al que te conectes, o que tu red haya cambiado, o que te tengas que conectar via proxy a ese servidor y no tengas tu proxy activado. Intenta con `git remote show origin` y ver la url a la que hace referencia

Comment: He intentado desde otros repositorios y tampoco me funciona. También intenté ese último comando que escribiste y me aparece el mismo error.

Comment: Tratándose del puerto 22, tranquilamente podría ser un firewall que te está desconectando. Puedes tratar de establecer una conexión ssh al servidor con el repositorio? Así: `$ ssh git@github.com`. Si la conexión es exitosa, github te a a desconectar pero te a a salir esto: `Hi fulanita! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`. Mientras no puedas establecer la conexión con ssh desde ese equipo desde el que estás tratando de hacer push, git no va a poder usar ssh como transporte (y tendrías que probar con https).